# SerializeField and Range(0, 1) in Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity

I want know What is the Use Of [SerializeField] and [Range(0,1)] in Unity3D.

Comment: -1 "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear [...]"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[SerializeField]` and `[Range(x,y)]` are both attributes, which can offer powerful utility to your script. If you are ever unsure of an attribute (or even if you are just curious) you should have a read through the [references provided by the Attributes section, in the Unity API contents](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AddComponentMenu.html). You may find *other* attributes you did not know about that make your life a lot easier.

`[SerializeField]` tells Unity that you want to serialise that field, which in turn, forces it to display in the inspector. You might say "why would I need that? They already display in the inspector", and in most cases, you would be correct. This attribute is sparingly used, most commonly to display `private` variables in the inspector. There are some restrictions, for instance, you can not serialize a `static` field or a `Dictionary`. You can read more about the limitations (and work arounds) at [the API reference](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SerializeField.html).

`[Range(x,y)]` tells Unity that you want to restrict that field to a particular range of numbers, `x` and `y`. As such, it is only compatible with `float` and `int` variables. When you use this attribute, the variable will be displayed in the inspector as a *slide bar* that enforces the provided constraint, as opposed to the default input field you are probably use to. You can even tell it if you want the scroll bar to *count up* or *count down*. You can read more about the application at [the API reference](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RangeAttribute.html).

Comment: I got clear vision about this topic.